# JSON Request works in Javascript but not in Nodejs (statusCode: 403)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I want to request a simple JSON File in NodeJS. With Javascript and jQuery it works like a charm:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://www.younow.com/php/api/broadcast/info/curId=0/user=Peter', function(json) {
      if (json["errorCode"] > 0) {
        console.log("Offline");
        $('#ampel').addClass('red');
      } else {
        console.log("Online");
        $('#ampel').addClass('green');
      }
  });
})
```

But i can't get it to work with NodeJS:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://www.younow.com/php/api/broadcast/info/curId=0/user=Peter',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/javascript'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
}

request(options, callback);
```

The StatusCode is always 403 and i can't work with the data. Can somebody help me, so i can get the same result like with jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: the header you are sending isn't the same as what jQuery is sending, but i doubt that's the cause.

Comment: 403 is generally the status code for "Forbidden". As @KevinB alludes to, it might be the `Content-Type` header. You generally request JSON with a header like `application/json` rather than `application/javascript`. It may also be something on the service side that blocks certain user agent strings.

Comment: no, the content type for "sending" data shouldn't be application/json or application/javascript if you aren't sending either. In this case no data is being sent other than what is in the url, so content-type isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution with Mike McCaughan's help:

I had to send a different user-agent to get a 200 response. The code looks like this now:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://www.younow.com/php/api/broadcast/info/curId=0/user=',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  var str = JSON.parse(body);
  if (str.errorCode > 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```